# FTP error when changing directories

Tags: windows, linux, ftp

I am trying to transfer files from Windows to a [vsFTPd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) server running on Linux. I can successfully transfer files to the home directory, but when I change the directory, I get an error. Below is a transcript demonstrating the problem.

```
C:\>ftp
ftp> open 10.50.0.21
Connected to 10.50.0.21.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
User (10.50.0.21:(none)): user1
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.

ftp> put D:/rez2g.ahk
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Ok to send data.
226 File receive OK.
ftp: 2401 bytes sent in 0.00Seconds 2401000.00Kbytes/sec.

ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
apache-tomcat-6.0.29
rez2g.ahk
victor.war
226 Directory send OK.
ftp: 48 bytes received in 0.00Seconds 48000.00Kbytes/sec.

ftp> cd 1/
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> pwd
257 "/home/user1/1"

ftp> put D:/rez2g.ahk
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
553 Could not create file.
```

Answer (score 1):

There has been an old issue with SELINUX that didn't allow FTP users to write in their home paths.
As far as I've seen, you can fix it in two ways:
[1] Disable selinux (not recommended for production environment)
[2] execute the following command as root (preferred one):

```
setsebool -P ftp_home_dir=1
```

Edit:
Can you make sure `write_enable=YES` is added in /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf?
Edit 2:

I thught of several other things that may be an issue, but are fairly easy to check:
File already exists, but you have no permissions to overwrite it
Disk is full (or quota reached)

Also, this may be a weird umask issue, with vsftp overriding. Are folders you create 644?
For user1 user, what is the output of `umask` command?

Comment: executed the above command and then i executed ftp but still the error remains as it is

Comment: @vinod I edited the post. Something silly crossed my mind, but it's too obvious and thus quite easy to oversee :-)

Comment: in /etc i don't have vsftpd.conf.
i have the .conf file in the location "/etc/vsftpd"
when i changed it also results the same error

Comment: @vinod I made a mistake, you are correct. It should be /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

Comment: the output for unmask is 0002

Comment: @vinod I believe it should be 0022, but I may be wrong. What happens when you set 'local_umask=022'? What is chmod of uploaded files?

Comment: @vinod, additionally, is there anything useful in /var/log/vsftpd.log or /var/log/message?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2623/discussion-between-vinod-and-extremko)

Comment: there is no useful infomation in the log and message files...
 
even i tried to change umask and ran it but no progress..i uploading the files from windows

Comment: @vinod, sorry friend, I'm all out of ideas :/

Comment: @vinod, Did you have any luck with this? I would be very interested to see the solution if you got it.

Comment: still now no luck at all @extremko

Comment: @vinod, hope you don't mind me necroing the old issue, but - did you succeed eventually? :) It would be good to know what happened.

Comment: left the issue and continued with other wrk